# How to return shortest string in an array with mixed data types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The task is to return the shortest string in an array with mixed data types, for example if we have the following array:

var arr1 = [1,9,"word1", "elephant", 5, "go", 19];

I need to make it so word "go" is returned.

I have this code but I need a method where I don't have to declare ultra long string :D like I did here:

---

```
var word = "SuperSuperLongLooooooongLooooooooooongVeryLoooooooooooongString";

function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(arr) {
// your code here
if (arr[0] === undefined){

      return "";

  }
 for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
  if (typeof arr[x] === "string" && arr[x].length < word.length){

      word = arr[x];

  } 

 }

 if (word.length === 0){

      return "";

  }
 return word;
}

findShortestWordAmongMixedElements([4, 'two', 2, 'three']); // returns "two"
```

There are some additional tasks like checking if array is empty and some other tiny bits, in case you are wondering why is there extra stuff in the code.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone, it's working as it's supposed to.

Comment: What if there are multiple strings of the same length? Do you need to return all of them, just the first, just the last?

Comment: Yes, I have to leave the one that had lowest index, but that's OK, I just need to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and return the smallest string.

```js
var array = [1, 9, "word1", "elephant", 5, "go", 19],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return typeof a !== 'string' || r !== undefined && r.length < a.length ? r : a;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Array.filter()** to delete non string elements and **Array.sort()** to have shortest element at the first place :

```js
var arr1 = [1,9,"word1", "elephant", 5, "go", 19];
var result = arr1.filter(x => isNaN(x)).sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length)[0];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the first string you find as word

if you find another string check if its shorter >>> replace word with the shorter one

else >>> check next

Comment: Do you mind adding a sample code on your idea how to do that inside a for loop, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter` and `reduce`, assuming you can make use of ES6's arrow functions, this will work:

```
arr1.filter(x => typeof x === 'string').reduce((shortest, x) => shortest === null || x.length < shortest.length ? x : shortest , null);
```

To explain how:

`.filter(x => typeof x === 'string')` filters the array and returns all the strings.

`.reduce((shortest, x) => ..., null)` applies a function on each of the items, modifying the `shortest` parameter on each pass. On the first pass it takes `null` to be the value of `shortest`, and in the case of the above code it uses the value of the current `x` if `shortest` is currently `null` or if `x` is shorter than `shortest`.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my pseudo code:

`let someArr = ['tiger', 'lion', 1, 'cat', 3, 4, 'horse', 'takin'];`


`1. if (!someArr.length) return '';
2. var newArr = someArr.filter(fn(elem) => return typeof elem === 'string'));
3. if (!newArr.length) return '';
4. newArr.filter(fn(acc,curr) => acc.length > curr.length ? acc : curr)
Output: cat`

`*Explanation*
1. Check if the array is empty. If it is then return an empty string:
2. Use the filter function to filter out only the values that are string and store it in a different variable.
3. Check if the new array is also empty. If it doesn't then return an empty string (this is make sure if the original array had no string values, or only had integers).
4. Take this new array and apply the reduce function to get the shortest string.`

Comment: Kind of late, that was 2 months ago :D